# Send live stream packets to youtube with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client, nodejs-stream

So I'm trying to create an application that will be able to send packets to Youtube as a live stream. So basically I enter my url to the program (rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2) and then it would start streaming and sending packets of an image of youtube. I've looking everywhere and I'm not sure if this is possible with nodejs. So basically, I would be able to live stream to Youtube 24/7 with my nodejs application. Please feel free to comment any question.

Comment: wow, i guess this is impossible since no one has answered

Comment: Have been looking for a way to do this for some time now, please respond if you ever find a way to do it

Comment: Have you got any success? I am trying to implement the same functionality but stucked on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about image. But if you have a video then you can stream it to youtube with `ffmpeg`.

## Method: 1

Without nodejs it can be done with the cli like this. Open the cli where your video file is stored. And run the follwing command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i vieo_you_wanna_stream.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/SECRET_STREAM_KEY
```

## Method: 2

If you really need to stream from nodejs server then you  can do the following:
Create a file called `runCommand.js` with these lines of code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
module.exports = (cmd, args, onData, onFinish) => {
    var proc = spawn(cmd, args.split(' '));
    proc.stdout.on('data', onData);
    proc.stderr.setEncoding("utf8")
    proc.stderr.on('data', err => console.log(err) );
    proc.on('close', onFinish);
}
```

Now in your `app.js` file put these lines of codes:

```
const runCommand = require('./runCommand')

runCommand(
  'ffmpeg',
  '-re -i vieo_you_wanna_stream.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/SECRET_STREAM_KEY',
  (data) => console.log(data),
  () => console.log('finished')
)
```

Now from cli run

```
node app.js
```

If your video path, `ffmpeg` and your youtube rtmp link is corrent the it will immediately start the stream.

### Note:

If you really want to stream only image to youtube with this method, then you can convert your image to a video with any kind of converter. And use this method to stream the video to youtube.